# Using variables to reference columns and range in R1C1 formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use variable in `Vlookup` formula in R1C1 form.  I am not able to get the syntax right for table array.

I tried this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[" & -39 - a & "],'Tmp-UPCR'!C1:C&a+1,&a+1,0)" 'Check the formula
```

The code I am using this in is:

```
Dim a As Integer
For a = 1 To i
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[" & -39 - a & "],'Tmp-UPCR'!C1:C&a+1,&a+1,0)" 'Check the formula
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select     
Next a
```

How could I get this formula working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your formula with:

```
"=VLOOKUP(RC[" & -39 - a & "],'Tmp-UPCR'!C1:C" & a + 1 & "," & a + 1 & ",0)"
```

However, you can avoid all this `Select` and `ActiveCell` and use directly the `For` loop below:

```
For a = 1 To i
    ' modify Column A below to the column where you want to put your formula
    Range("A" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[" & -39 - a & "],'Tmp-UPCR'!C1:C" & a + 1 & "," & a + 1 & ",0)" 'Check the formula
Next a
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and suggesting faster alternative :) The formula works fine.